# Move constructor for a list of Person objects

Tags: c++, constructor, c++17, stdmove

I am writing a simple code, in which I have a list of objects of class Person.
The Person class

```
class Person
{
    private:
        std::string name;
        std::string surname;
        int year;
        
    public:
        Person(const std::string& personName,
               const std::string& personSurname, 
               const int& personYear ):
               name(personName), surname(personSurname), year(personYear) {}
               
        Person(const Person& p): name(p.name), surname(p.surname), year(p.year) { }
        
        Person(Person &&p) noexcept: name(std::move(p.name)), surname(std::move(p.surname)), year(std::move(p.year)) { }
        
        int getYear()
        {
            return year;
        }
        
        void print()
        {
            std::cout << name << " " << surname << " " << year << std::endl;
        }
};
```

in which, the move constructor is

```
        Person(Person &&p) noexcept: name(std::move(p.name)), surname(std::move(p.surname)), year(std::move(p.year)) { }
```

I also have the node structure

```
struct node
{
    Person data;
    node *next;
    inline node(const std::string& personName,
                const std::string& personSurname, 
                const int& personYear): data(personName, personSurname, personYear), next(nullptr) { }
    inline node(const Person& personToInsert): data(personToInsert), next(nullptr) {} 
    inline node(Person &&personToInsert): data(std::move(personToInsert)), next(nullptr) {}
};
```

whose move constructor is

```
    inline node(Person &&personToInsert): data(std::move(personToInsert)), next(nullptr) {}
```

and finally I have the list class

```
class list
{
    private:
    node *head;
    
    public:
    list();
    ~list();
    void insert(const std::string&, const std::string&, const int& );
    void insert(const Person& );
    void insert(Person &&);
    void print();
};
```

whose move constructor is

```
void list::insert(Person &&personToInsert) {
    node *new_node = new node(std::move(personToInsert));
    if(head == nullptr || (head->data).getYear() >= (new_node->data).getYear())
    {
        new_node->next = head;
        head = new_node;
    }
    else
    {
        node *current = head;
        while(current->next != nullptr && (current->next->data).getYear() < (new_node->data).getYear())
        {
            current = current->next;
        }
        new_node->next = current->next;
        current->next = new_node;
    } 
}
```

**My question is:** inside the move constructors, is the use of `std::move` correct? Particularly in the first line of code of `list::insert`

Comment: OT: It seems that the automatically-generated move constructor of `Person` would be perfectly fine. The same holds for copy constructor. You don't need to define them explicitly.

Comment: @DanielLangr 
Of course. I did not specified that it is for educational purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> inside the move constructors, is the use of `std::move` correct?

Yes.

> Particularly in the first line of code of `list::insert`

This is correct, too.

Note, however, that there are two minor things I would like to point out. First, there is no need to manually define the move constructor for `Person`. If your class doesn't do manual resource handling (memory, IO handles etc.), just rely on the special member functions that the compiler generates for you. In this case, I would just remove `Person`'s move and copy constructor.

Second,

```
inline node(Person &&personToInsert)
```

is *not* a move constructor. It's an ordinary constructor that happens to take an rvalue-reference parameter. Move constructors are for constructing an object from an rvalue reference of their own type.

Third,

```
void list::insert(Person &&personToInsert)
```

is not a constructor at all - it's an ordinary member function that happens to accept an rvalue parameter.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. Sometimes, like now, I do not use the proper terminology.

Comment: Using the proper terminology in C++ is a never ending endeavor at any stage of acquired familiarity with the language :)